# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1 from OnChildRemoved Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to remove data from my recyclerview and let it be updated in the mobile ui as well. It is an **android** app. I am able to **delete** the data alright but I always have to leave that page and come back when I make the changes. I tried making some modifications to the **onChildRemoved** method but I started getting **crashes** upon making this change. What do I do? Below is my code.

MainActivity.java

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
List<DataSnapshot> listData;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
MyCart.MyAdapter adapter;


recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

listData = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new MyCart.MyAdapter(listData);
adapter.setHasStableIds(true);

GetDataFirebase();

private void GetDataFirebase() {
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Customers")
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("My Cart");
    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Items students = dataSnapshot.getValue(Items.class);

            listData.add(dataSnapshot);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int index = listData.indexOf(dataSnapshot);
            listData.remove(index);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Adapter Class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCart.MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<DataSnapshot> list;

    public MyAdapter(List<DataSnapshot> List) {
        this.list = List;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyCart.MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final DataSnapshot studentSnapshot = list.get(position);

        final Items students = studentSnapshot.getValue(Items.class);

        final String list_user_id = studentSnapshot.getKey();

        holder.item_name.setText(students.getItem_name());
        holder.item_price.setText(students.getItem_price());

        Picasso.with(holder.item_image.getContext()).load(students.getItem_image()).placeholder(R.drawable.no_image_two).into(holder.item_image);

        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DatabaseReference prod_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Customers").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("My Cart").child(list_user_id);
                prod_ref.removeValue();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(MyCart.this, "Item removed from cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyCart.MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_item_layout, parent, false);

        return new MyCart.MyAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView item_name, item_price;
        ImageView item_image;
        ImageView delete;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            item_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            item_price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);

            item_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);

            delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_item);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you call notifyDatasetChanged() method after deleting data inside the adapter class ?

Comment: No please. Let me try that asap

Comment: ok please add adapter class code to question too

Comment: I have edited my question. When I added the notifyDatasetChanged() method, it still crashed. Am I missing something?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

When `dataSnapshot` does not exist in list, it returns `-1`. Index of list start from `0`. Therefore, you're this getting error. You need to add a guard check here like:

```
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            int index = listData.indexOf(dataSnapshot);
            if(index > 0) {
               listData.remove(index);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Tayyab. Even though the crash has stopped, the ui is not updating. I still have to leave the ui and come back to see the changes. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Oh!, I just fix the exception issue. Updated the code please check now. Hopefully, your problem will be solved now.

Comment: Hey man, you know how I could add some sort of animation when it is deleting? I read about notifyitemremoved but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello bro any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DatabaseReference prod_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Customers").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("My Cart").child(list_user_id);
            prod_ref.removeValue();

            //add/modify these two lines here 
            list.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });
```

And one more change you need to do 
// move this toast to onChildRemoved method and clear the other code from there

```
Toast.makeText(MyCart.this, "Item removed from cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

like

```
@Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //remove these line these will raise the exception and Toast here 
        int index = listData.indexOf(dataSnapshot);
        listData.remove(index);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Hey man, you know how I could add some sort of animation when it is deleting? I read about notifyitemremoved but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?